# How can I write the following statement as a constraint?

Tags: constraints

I have the following condition:

- If $x = 0$ and $c=0$ then $z=1$.
- If $x>0$ and $c=1$ then $z = 1$.
- If $x>0$ and $c=0$ then $z = 0$.

I find the constraint $x(1-c) \geqslant 1-z$, but it misses the last point.

**EDIT**

The variables $z$ and $c$ are binary variables.

Comment: I don't get how the inequality encompasses any of the given equalities. For instance with $x=0=c$, one gets $0\ge 1-z$.How does $z=1$ follow?

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question according to your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$z=-sgn(x)+sgn(c)+1$$ does the job.